# jQuery - if (this.checked) with multiple input groups

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run the function on the `input` for each group of `.tagboxes` but the code is only working as intended on the second group and does not execute properly on the first. Is the problem with the `if` statement, sepcifically

```
if (this.checked) {
   $input.not(this).trigger("change");
}
```

Or is there an issue with how `each` is set up?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function darkness(color) {
    color.replace(/^\D+|\)/g, "").trim();
    //console.log(color);
    var rgb = color.split(",");
    //console.log(rgb);
    var final =
      parseInt(rgb[0], 10) + parseInt(rgb[1], 10) + parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
    //console.log(final);
    if (final < 384) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  $(".tagboxes").each(function() {
    $group = $(this);
    $input = $group.find("input");
    $input.change(
      (function($group) {
        return function() {
          var label = $(this).next("label");
          var tagbox = $(this).closest(".tagbox");
          var color = label.data("rgb");
          var rgb = `rgb(${color})`;
          var contrast = darkness(color) ? "#202124" : "#fdfdfd";

          if (this.checked) {
            $input.not(this).trigger("change");
            tagbox.css({
              "background-color": rgb,
              color: contrast,
              "border-color": rgb,
              color: contrast
            });
          } else {
            tagbox.css({
              "background-color": "#fff",
              color: "",
              "border-color": ""
            });
          }
        };
      })($group)
    );
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#m_clear").on("click", function() {
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).trigger("change");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tagboxes {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="m_clear">Clear All</button>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i0" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="i0">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i1" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="i1">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i2" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="i2">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
  </label>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x0" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="x0">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x1" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="x1">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x2" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="x2">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the scope of the variables from global to function scope by using `var` before the variable like `var $group =` and `var $input =`. Otherwise the global variable will be used which will have as values the second line.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function darkness(color) {
    color.replace(/^\D+|\)/g, "").trim();
    //console.log(color);
    var rgb = color.split(",");
    //console.log(rgb);
    var final =
      parseInt(rgb[0], 10) + parseInt(rgb[1], 10) + parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
    //console.log(final);
    if (final < 384) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  $(".tagboxes").each(function() {
    var $group = $(this);
    var $input = $group.find("input");
    $input.change(
      (function($group) {
        return function() {
          var label = $(this).next("label");
          var tagbox = $(this).closest(".tagbox");
          var color = label.data("rgb");
          var rgb = `rgb(${color})`;
          var contrast = darkness(color) ? "#202124" : "#fdfdfd";

          if (this.checked) {
            $input.not(this).trigger("change");
            tagbox.css({
              "background-color": rgb,
              color: contrast,
              "border-color": rgb,
              color: contrast
            });
          } else {
            tagbox.css({
              "background-color": "#fff",
              color: "",
              "border-color": ""
            });
          }
        };
      })($group)
    );
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#m_clear").on("click", function() {
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).trigger("change");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tagboxes {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="m_clear">Clear All</button>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i0" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="i0">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i1" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="i1">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i2" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="i2">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
  </label>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x0" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="x0">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x1" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="x1">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x2" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="x2">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively they could pass `$input` as another parameter to the IIFE. But the IIFE is only needed because they didn't scope the variables properly.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited somewhere in your code. You don't need to use IIFE inside the `change` event. About the background color trouble, you can reset all of the background to default value, then you just need to apply the new background for the current element which contains the input.

```
$(this).closest('.tagboxes').find('input').each(function() {
    $(this).closest(".tagbox").css({
        "background-color": "#fff",
        color: "",
        "border-color": ""
    });
});

if (this.checked) {
    tagbox.css({
        "background-color": rgb,
        color: contrast,
        "border-color": rgb,
        color: contrast
    });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function darkness(color) {
        color.replace(/^\D+|\)/g, "").trim();
        //console.log(color);
        var rgb = color.split(",");
        //console.log(rgb);
        var final =
            parseInt(rgb[0], 10) + parseInt(rgb[1], 10) + parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
        //console.log(final);
        if (final < 384) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $(".tagboxes").each(function() {
        $group = $(this);
        $input = $group.find("input");
        $input.change(function() {
            var label = $(this).next("label");
            var tagbox = $(this).closest(".tagbox");
            var color = label.data("rgb");
            var rgb = `rgb(${color})`;
            var contrast = darkness(color) ? "#202124" : "#fdfdfd";

            $(this).closest('.tagboxes').find('input').each(function() {
                $(this).closest(".tagbox").css({
                    "background-color": "#fff",
                    color: "",
                    "border-color": ""
                });
            });

            if (this.checked) {
                tagbox.css({
                    "background-color": rgb,
                    color: contrast,
                    "border-color": rgb,
                    color: contrast
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#m_clear").on("click", function() {
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                $(this).trigger("change");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.tagboxes {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="m_clear">Clear All</button>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i0" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="i0">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i1" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="i1">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="i2" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="i2">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
  </label>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="tagboxes">

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x0" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="255,64,129" for="x0">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Lobster</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x1" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="49,231,182" for="x1">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Tuna</b>
  </label>
  </div>

  <div class="tagbox">
    <input id="x2" type="radio" name="radio2">
    <label data-rgb="0,0,255" for="x2">
    <b class='text--tagbox'>Pine</b>
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```